# How may I receive FB messenger messages in Flex Agent Console

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-functions, twilio-flex

I'm trying to use Messenger channel in a Flex instance, however, I haven't been able to make it work.  The closest I've got is using at the Facebook channel configuration the function url INBOUND MESSAGE as callback url, this way I receive the messenger notification in Flex Agent console but there's no message in it.

If I use the webhook url provided by the Flow created in Studio I get a XML response error because it's not providing the expected format.

Sadly I find documentation really incomplete and scarce so I haven't been able to figure this out.

Anyone has a proper documentation on how to make facebook messenger work with Flex??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Apologies for the lack of documentation here, we are continuing to work on that. I'm told that the easiest thing to do would be to follow this guide for [connecting WhatsApp to Flex](https://www.twilio.com/blog/whatsapp-and-flex-in-minutes-html), substituting Facebook for WhatsApp.

Let me know how that goes for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming late to this thread, but I'm trying to go through the process of connecting Facebook Messenger into Twilio. This seems to be the latest source on how to achieve this: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018783533-Integrating-Facebook-Messenger-with-Twilio-Flex

While we were able to see actual messages sent into Flex (following a Studio flow to achieve this), I would love to know how to convert the `messenger:1234566` type of id into something more legible, based on data from the Facebook User / Customer. A name and an email would suffice, and I'm sure it's the most requested use case.

@philnash - can you point us out to any more documentation on this?

Comment: hi elQueFaltaba, I am wondering if you can show the Facebook User name instead of "messenger:xxxx"? Thank You~~~~

Comment: Hi Benny. At the moment this is impossible. While working on our project we were in touch with Twilio on this matter and found out due to security restrictions on the graph api we no longer have any information on the user nor the conversation id (you could then call another facebook api endpoint to get user information from that)

So unless they have changed it in the last 4 months, this is not available yet.
Cheers

Comment: @philnash -- is my assumption above correct? I conducted some tests along Patrick K. and he passed that to the corresponding PM. Do we have news in this regard that you know of?